# PyICU works in Django shell but not on web server

Tags: python, django, icu, pyicu

I'm getting this error when trying to access ICU's Collator attribute on a staging server.

```
AttributeError at /...
'module' object has no attribute 'Collator'
```

When launching Django's shell and executing the exact same code, everything seems to be working just as well as it does locally. The code that is causing the error is:

```
import icu
    collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(get_language()))
    objects = [i for i in sorted(objects, key=attrgetter('city'), cmp=collator.compare)]
```

I've successfully installed ICU (`libicu52, libicu-dev`) via [Ondrej's PHP5 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5), as well as PyICU, both locally and on our staging server. The server running Ubuntu Server 13.10 with Python 2.7.5, Django 1.5.5, Nginx 1.4.1 and uWSGI 1.9.13.

Here's the full traceback:

```
File "/var/www/venv/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/venv/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/venv/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/.../pages/views.py" in get
  48.             return StoreListView.as_view(object=self.object)(request)
File "/var/www/venv/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/venv/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/venv/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get
  124.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
File "/var/www/.../geosearch/views.py" in get_queryset
  22.             objects = self.sort_objects(objects)
File "/var/www/.../geosearch/views.py" in sort_objects
  59.         collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(get_language()))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /...
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'Collator'
```

I managed to print ICU's `__dict__`, but it gives me an ICUError. Locally, ICU is returned with its actual attributes, including Collator.

```
ICUError=<class 'icu.ICUError'>,
__builtins__={'bytearray': <type 'bytearray'>,
'IndexError': <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>
[...]
```

What might be the reason the code is working as it should in Django's shell, but not through the web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a misconfiguration in uWSGI, and had nothing to do with PyICU or ICU. I figured out uWSGI was not using the packages installed in the virtualenv, so I had a second look in the uWSGI config file.

`chdir` was not set to the correct folder, instead it pointed to its parent folder.

Why all the other packages worked, I have no idea.